# to_csv error with pandas dataframe with timezone

Tags: python, pandas, timezone

The following code gives an error under the pandas 0.17 but work very well with the 0.16.2.

No problem with the `to_pickle` function but get an error with the `to_csv`.

Has someone a tip to deal with it ?

```
In[23]: new_index = pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31', freq = 'H', tz='Europe/Paris')
In[24]: df = pd.DataFrame({}, index = new_index)
In[25]: df['test'] = 1.
In[26]: df.to_pickle(r'test.h5')

In[27]: df.to_csv(r'test.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-27-2ced74ae66e1>", line 1, in <module>
    df.to_csv(r'test.csv')
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1289, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1494, in save
    self._save()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1594, in _save
    self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 1619, in _save_chunk
    quoting=self.quoting)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\index.py", line 1292, in to_native_types
    return values._format_native_types(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 746, in _format_native_types
    format = _get_format_datetime64_from_values(self, date_format)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 2191, in _get_format_datetime64_from_values
    is_dates_only = _is_dates_only(values)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\format.py", line 2145, in _is_dates_only
    values = DatetimeIndex(values)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\decorators.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py", line 344, in __new__
    ambiguous=ambiguous)
  File "pandas\tslib.pyx", line 3753, in pandas.tslib.tz_localize_to_utc (pandas\tslib.c:64516)
AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2015-10-25 02:00:00'), try using the 'ambiguous' argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known bug [#11619](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11619) and should be fixed in 0.17.1

The underlying issue is that your timeframe crosses from standard time to daylight saving time, which is the exact time showing in the error `AmbiguousTimeError: Cannot infer dst time from Timestamp('2015-10-25 02:00:00')`